# php if-statement doesn't echo a string inside a div's class?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Right now, the value of the variable `$thumbs_number` is +2.

When I place `<?php if ( $thumbs_number == 2 ) { echo "high-rated"; } ?>">` right before the closing `</div>` I do get an output: **high-rated**.

but when I place it inside the div's class: `<div class="topic-content <?php if ( $thumbs_number == 2 ) { echo "high-rated"; } ?>">`.

nothing is output.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Full code:

```
    <div class="topic-content <?php if ( $thumbs_number == 2 ) { echo "high-rated"; } ?>">
        <span class="topic-author-link"><?php bbp_reply_author_link( array( 'type' => 'name' ) ); ?></span>
        <span class="topic-post-date"><?php printf( __( '<span>%1$s</span> <span>at %2$s</span>', 'bbpress' ), get_the_date(), esc_attr( get_the_time() ) ); ?></span>

<?php echo time_ago(); ?>
<br />
<?php echo "$post->post_modified \n"; ?>

        <?php bbp_reply_admin_links(); ?>

        <?php bbp_reply_content(); ?>

        <div class="topic-like-count">
            <h4><?php wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(); ?></h4>

            <?php preg_match( '!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si' , wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(0, false, "", 0, "", false) , $n );
            $thumbs_number = strip_tags( $n[1] ); ?>

            <?php echo $thumbs_number; ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is "nothing" because you have it in your HTML syntax. You should view the source to see what is has outputted.

Comment: Hey it appears in the source code but it doesn't appear when I check it with firebug. What does this mean?

Comment: This means your HTML is invalid. Firebug shows the HTML after the browser parsed it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster so what's the proper way of adding that class using php?

Comment: @alexchenco We don't know what the classnames are. I assume you want to have a different class if the topic has X votes. You should write proper HTML to set your class (but you are on the right way).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the space had to be placed in the echo instead of the HTML part:

```
<div class="topic-content<?php if ( $thumbs_number == 2 ) { echo " high-rated"; } ?>">
```

Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is too much double quotes:

```
<div class="topic-content<?php if ( $thumbs_number == 2 ) { echo " high-rated"; } ?>">
```

You echo double quotes inside double quotes so it is invalid HTML.

Update: Your fix with space is still invalid, just your browser can fix it better.